# XSL: access variable value with xml attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

Having lines like this one

```
<COLUMN name="CATEGORY_" type="VARCHAR_M"/>
```

in my XML file.
With the help of an xlst file I want to replace VARCHAR_M with database dependent datatype.
Therefore I have set

```
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$DatabaseSystem = 'DB2'">
            <xsl:variable name="VARCHAR_S" select="'varchar(64)'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="VARCHAR_M" select="'varchar(255)'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="VARCHAR_B" select="'varchar(4000)'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="INTEGER" select="'integer'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$DatabaseSystem = 'Informix'">
            <xsl:variable name="VARCHAR_S" select="'varchar(64)'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="VARCHAR_M" select="'varchar(255)'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="VARCHAR_B" select="'lvarchar(4000)'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="INTEGER" select="'integer'"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

This

```
<xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
```

gives me the value of the attribute from xml, how can I use this as the name of the variable?

Something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="$@type"/>
```

.

Comment: You will have to choose a different approach I think, your variables are solely defined inside of the `xsl:when`, so you cannot even access them outside. And dynamic XPath evaluation is not part of the language in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. You might want to store your values in an XML structure and then select from that structure (you might need `exsl:node-set` or similar in XSLT 1.0), that way you can select value.

Comment: "*I want to replace VARCHAR_M with database dependent datatype.*" I don't see anything in your code that would lead to that. I suggest you explain the **logic** that needs to be applied here (with a more complete example of the input). Currently, this seems to be an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

If you ditch the <xsl:chose> and replace it with the same data as in xml you can do something like this...

```
<xsl:variable name="map">
    <db databaseSystem='DB2'>
        <type name="VARCHAR_S">varchar(64)</type>
        <type name="VARCHAR_M">varchar(255)</type>
        <type name="VARCHAR_B">varchar(400)</type>
        <type name="INTEGER">integer</type>
    </db>
    <db databaseSystem='Informix'>
        <type name="VARCHAR_S">varchar(64)</type>
        <type name="VARCHAR_M">varchar(255)</type>
        <type name="VARCHAR_B">varchar(400)</type>
        <type name="INTEGER">integer</type>
    </db>
</xsl:variable>
```

You can then pick up the value like so...

```
<xsl:value-of select="$map/db[@databaseSystem='DB2']/type[@name='VARCHAR_M']"/>
```

Clerly you wont be using with fixed strings and in your own code, you'll be replace the 'DB2' and 'VARCHAR_M' with variables or references to your *"Having lines like this one"* input